# Pass result of first observable to observable in switchMap

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using a switchMap to link two observables, however I need the result of the first observable to be available inside the second observable so that I can use the result to map the result of the second observable.

What's the syntax to enable using `res1` inside of the subscription?

```
this._signalRService.obs1.pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroyObservables),
          switchMap(res1 => {
                  if (this.idParam === res1) {
                      return this.getAllCustomCategoryGroups$();
                  }
                  return;
              }
          )).subscribe(groups => {
            let x = groups.map(group => groupId === res1); //res1 needed here to map groups 
      });
```

Three observables

```
 this._authService.loggedInUser$.pipe(switchMap((loggedInUser: LoggedInUser) => {
      return this._userSerialService.getUserSerial().pipe(switchMap(serial => {
          return this._usersService.getCurrentUser().pipe(switchMap(currentUser => [loggedInUser, currentUser, serial]))
        }),
      );
    })).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

Comment: This can be done using map operator to pass an object or array containing all the values you need. Previously this was done with result selector arguments https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Would you mind posting an answer with a code example? I'm really not sure what that would look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the emission from second observable into an array or object. Result selectors wouldn't help you here:

```
switchMap(res1 => {
  if (this.idParam === res1) {
    return this.getAllCustomCategoryGroups$().pipe(
      map(res2 => [res1, res2]),
    );
  }
  return EMPTY; // You have to return something here
}).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => { ... })
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. Am I able to strongly type the `[res1, res2]` array inside of the subscribe?

Comment: `[res1, res2]: [string, number]`

Comment: if you do `map(res2 => [res1, res2]) as const,` you'll get it defined as a tuple instead of an array

Comment: @martin Coming back to this as I have a similar use case, is it possible to do the same thing but with three observables? So that I switchMap twice and the final subscribe has a res that looks like `[res1, res2, res3]`? I've updated the question with code.